# Cisco AnyConnect causes OS X to kernel panic

Tags: snow-leopard, vpn, crash, kernel-panic

My Macbook Pro 15" (Early 2011 - the one with Thunderbolt port) constantly kernel panics whenever Cisco AnyConnect establishes connection.

The panic tends to happen in the first ~30 seconds after connection is established.

The crash log is available here:
https://gist.github.com/d947e73b0b6c17a863b7

Any thoughts?

Some details:
Macbook Pro 15" i7 Early 2011 (the one with Thunderbolt)
Cisco AnyConnect version 2.5.2019

PS. I asked this question on the Apple Support forum, but so far I have got no answer :(

**EDIT**: This problem originally occurs in Snow Leopard, but problem persists in Lion (10.7), even after a fresh install (not upgrade from 10.6)

Comment: Do you have to use the Cisco client? While I haven't used the AnyConnect client, I did use the Cisco VPN Client and had kernel panics with it. I switched to using the built-in VPN client over a year ago and haven't had a kernel panic since then.

Comment: @barryj: AnyConnect is using SSLVPN while the built-in VPN support only works over IPSec. I don't think I can use the built-in VPN, sadly :(

Comment: Cisco now has at least version 3.0.5080 of AnyConnect -- any chance you can upgrade your AnyConnect client?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue on an iMac running OSX Lion (10.7.3). I [submitted a bug report to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) and [tweeted at @anyconnect](https://twitter.com/#!/drewgeraets/status/192341312383631360). You will need to work with Cisco support or use another version of the app unless we can narrow down the specific setting that is causing this crash.

Comment: Was there any resolution and information on version of AnyConnect that causes this?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this issue, and wrote about it here :

http://technie.net/kernel-panic-on-macbooks-20102011-with-cisco-anyconnect/

There's a bug in Cisco AnyConnect, but following the guide on the link, it will be able to work.

On Macbook Pro 15″ and 17″ (Late 2010, Early 2011 – the one with Thunderbolt port) sometimes kernel panics whenever Cisco AnyConnect establishes connection.

Usually the Panic comes approx 30 seconds after a connection is established.

I found out that the following solves this issue :

If your macbook kernel panics, reboot it.

– close all apps

– shutdown macbook from menu.

– Make sure the powercord is in

– Reset the SMC by pressing Shift+Crtrl+Alt + Power button for at least 5 seconds

– Startup the macbook

– Connect using AnyConnect.

This has worked for me so far. It’s not optimal, Cisco should definately fix their client, but this is a way to at least be able to connect.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.